# how to use android sliding up panel

Tags: android

I have downloaded the umano sliding up panel from https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Imported it into the workspace and added reference to it in my project.

Next I copied and pasted the following into a new layout -

Here is the Code :

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:panelHeight="68dp"
    sothree:shadowHeight="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Main Content"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:text="The Awesome Sliding Up Panel"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

But I am getting an error unbound prefix.

What is wrong in my code?

And How can i fix this ?

Comment: can you post logcat error?

Comment: where is the namespace for android?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing namespace for android

Also this

```
xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Should be

```
xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/yourpackagename"
```

So it should be

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/yourpackagename"
```

considering you have custom attributes

Edit:

Looks like you are using

https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel

Its a library project and you must reference it in your andorid project. Scodnly missing android namespace as mentioned. The below should fix it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
    xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    sothree:panelHeight="68dp"
    sothree:shadowHeight="4dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Main Content"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center|top"
        android:text="The Awesome Sliding Up Panel"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: @windupurnomo it should be

Comment: @Raghunandan  Can i set `SlidingUpPanelLayout` Center default state ??

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i don't understand what you mean by center default state.

Comment: @Raghunandan Ji Okay . Can i make this only Center and Top state ?

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i haven't used this library in a long time. I guess its possible. gotta try it

Answer (score 3):

You can use BottomSheetBehavior from android support library from google as alternative. `compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'`
You can checkout my sample https://github.com/andrisasuke/Android-SlidingUp-Panel

Answer (score 2):

I also implemented a SlidingUpPaneLayout, based on the SlidingPaneLayout, but the slide direction is 
vertical you can slide up and down for the top view, it's more simple,just two views and no more attribute need to set.see at github,https://github.com/chenjishi/SlidingUpPaneLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.chenjishi.slideupdemo.SlidingUpPaneLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sliding_up_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#FFF"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="BOTTOM"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#333"/>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/top_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="#009588"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TOP"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:textColor="#333"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Jishi Chen , how to restrict the top_view height. I want to drag the top view only to half of the screen

Comment: @PrabhuM in SlidingUpPaneLayout.java,you can change     private static final int DEFAULT_OVERHANG_SIZE = 32; // dp;
to what you want:)

Comment: I guess, as per ur comment in code SlidingUpPaneLayout.java, DEFAULT_OVERHANG_SIZE will make at least this much of a sliding pane will remain visible to indicate that there is more content available. But , What I am asking is, When I drag the Sliding up panel , It should stop at half of the screen(or 250dp height) instead of covering the complete screen.

Comment: @JishiChen,  prabhu

I have same question as prabhu. You code does not allow to drag till half of screen. Can you tell us how can we do so.

prabhu's question: "I guess, as per ur comment in code SlidingUpPaneLayout.java, DEFAULT_OVERHANG_SIZE will make at least this much of a sliding pane will remain visible to indicate that there is more content available. But , What I am asking is, When I drag the Sliding up panel , It should stop at half of the screen(or 250dp height) instead of covering the complete screen."

Answer (score 1):

If you want to slide your main body along with sliding part then only then add 
   umanoParallaxOffset attribute otherwise remove it

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/hidden_panel"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:gravity="bottom"
sothree:umanoClipPanel="false"
sothree:umanoDragView="@+id/dragView"
sothree:umanoFadeColor="@android:color/transparent"
sothree:umanoOverlay="true"
sothree:umanoPanelHeight="@dimen/_69sdp"
sothree:umanoShadowHeight="@dimen/_4sdp">

//Main body content

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        Body...........

</FrameLayout>

//Sliding content

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_panel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        Body...........

</FrameLayout>
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```

Don't forget it!
sothree:umanoOverlay="true"

```
<style name="AppTheme">
<item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

you are getting unbound prefix error means you are done with referencing the library, you just need to modify xmlns attributes and make the slidingUpPanelLayout the root and you are done. dont't forgot to change "com.example.slidinguppanel" with your package name. 
Hope it will fix your problem.

```
<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.slidinguppanel"
android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom"
sothree:panelHeight="68dp"
sothree:shadowHeight="4dp">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Main Content"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center|top"
    android:text="The Awesome Sliding Up Panel"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>
```