# How to make a sample demo project with Android Sliding panel in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

For a complete beginner like me, can anyone tell me how to just create sample demo application using "https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel" in Android Studio version "0.8.6".

I have followed these mentioned steps in order to include the Android Sliding panel library
1) Download the latest stable release from the following location"https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel/releases"

2)extract the zip folder

From the you tube video "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1MyBO9z7ojk"

3)Created a folder in the root directory with name "libraries" (application name is "slidingPanelTesting2")

4)Copied the extracted directory in to the folder libraries

5) In the settings.gradle changed the first line of code to

`include ':app', ':libraries:AndroidSlidingUpPanel:AndroidSlidingUpPanel-2.0.1'`

6)In the poject structure (file->projectstructure)
  click on "app" of modules section, In Dependencies tab added the module Dependency

```
libraries:AndroidSlidingUpPanel:AndroidSlidingUpPanel-2.0.1
```

7)After clicking Apply I get the following error
 `Error:Configuration with name 'default' not found.`
[image]

It would be great if some one can answer as I have many posts with the same problem without any answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's much easier to add this library to your Android Studio project. First of all undo all of your previous steps - they're simply not needed.

Open the `build.gradle` file of your `app`folder and add the following lines to the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:+'
}
```

Done! Android Studio may complain that the repositories stuff doesn't belong there so just move it to the build.gradle file of the project itself instead of the app module.

Here's how your build.gradle files should look like in the end:

[image: explanatory picture]

#### Edit

As `Scott Barta` mentioned in the comments, mavenCentral() isn't needed if there's already jcenter() in your repository list. jcenter() seems like a superset of mavenCentral() - Read more here: [SO: Android buildscript repositories. jcenter VS mavencentral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24852219/android-buildscript-repositories-jcenter-vs-mavencentral)

Comment: this is simplest possible answer any user can get, Thanks man :)

Comment: and for some one who got an error  "unbound prefix" see this page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22928573/how-to-use-android-sliding-up-panel

Comment: It's generally unnecessary to use mavenCentral as a repository if you've already got jcenter.

Comment: How can i set the height of minimized SlidingUpPanel?I want my panel should display four images of gridview even when in minimized state.User can slide it to top to see complete gridview.How can i increase the height of minimized sludinguppanel so that it can show more content?